# BlueSnap BuyNow integration - why can't I see the Apple Pay button?

Tags: iframe, applepay, bluesnap

I added BlueSnap BuyNow payment page in an iFrame in my website, to handle the checkout. One of the reasons I chose it was because the BuyNow supports Apple Pay built-in (I don't want a separate integration for it). It worked for a while, but recently I noticed the button for ApplePay is gone.

I changed the settings (currency, country...), added a parameter in the iFrame URL to force the payment method, and nothing.

How can I bring the button back? are there any specific preconditions I should know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the BuyNow Checkout page allows iFrames with ApplePay on test condition only. In production environments, we only offer the Applepay payment method in a full mode Checkout page and not as an embedded iFrame.

In general, the ApplePay payment method support within the BuyNow depends on a few conditions which are dictated by Apple. To see it, you should:

1. The merchant must be boarded to ApplePay
2. The shopper must use a Mac device to see the BuyNow page.
3. The Shopper must use Safari as their browser.
4. No custom fields are presented in the BuyNow (it will be supported in future versions, though)
5. The BuyNow does not contain any mandatory fields other than the minimal – don't use skins which make fields like "company" mandatory.
6. The total is greater than zero – seems obvious, but it could happen.
7. shopper country is supported by ApplePay – the country code must be in this list: ca, us, fr, ie, ru, es, ch, uk, au, cn, hk, jp, nz, sg, tw, do.
8. No iFrames (unless it's the BuyNow test flow)
9. Coupon is not required in the BuyNow. It could be added – but only if it's filled in automatically.
10. Cart does not contain recurring payments while Wire is the selected payment method. An interesting end-case, but it will make the button disappear.

I hope this helps. I would recommend you consider going full-frame for the BuyNow, so you can use this feature.

P.S 
The ApplePay (unlike other payment methods) can not be auto-selected while opening the Checkout page using run-time parameter in the URL.